# Change max_connections Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, connections

how i can change max_connections on Postgresql.conf without restart service Postgresql?
Systemctl reload postgresql.service not work with this conf.

Comment: Documentation clearly states: "This parameter can only be set at server start."

Comment: The answer is simple: you can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been posted as a comment (by mustaccio), but to make it a clear answer, from the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-connection.html):

> This parameter can only be set at server start.

In other words, you **must** restart PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know there is no workaround unless you restart.

So first you need to get current value from `SHOW max_connections` and then change via command `ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections TO 'xxx'` x- is your value. After this you need a restart

Also you can use pgbouncer to handle your connections if other one you mentioned is not working